# Which of the following are true for the sequence $f_n(x)=(-x)^n$ for $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pointwise-convergence

> Which of the following are true for the sequence $f_n(x)=(-x)^n$ for $x\in[0,1]$
>
> 1. there exists a pointwise convergent subsequence of $f_n$.
> 2. $f_n$ has no pointwise convergent subsequence.
> 3. $f_n$ converges pointwise everywhere.
> 4. $f_n$ has exactly one pointwise convergent subsequence.

By Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem, option 1 is true. Also for $x=1$, $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$ which is not convergent. so option 3 is not true. Also option 2 is false. But I am not sure about the option 4. How can I check this option? Any hint or help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Saying that $f_n(1)$ is not convergent "anywhere" sounds a bit strange. You are right that it doesn't converge at $x = 1$, and therefore 3. is false, but "anywhere" in this context usually means "for any $x$", and you've already specified $x = 1$. "For $x= 1$ the sequence doesn't converge for any $x$" is not a good sentence to write.

Comment: fixed @Arthur..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2n+1}$.